# How do I ungzip a string like this

Tags: kotlin, gzip

I have this string:

`H4sIAAAAAAAA/6VRPQvCMBD9K+VmBxF0yNZV6KLiIiJnc4RgPkqSilL6371o0Yo4iFNy79679y7p4Gh8fYogdh1oCeJRw2Q4BdCZXOIag2IWkxLZTN/3jNVJe8ekpdcO+smXEY3BK4XDwP4c9bjdkSxPl+wnMWGGHFpisA3WW+jZNBqfQEzvbmPZ0RwSqpHSN0O6UsoiNlhT5G7mCNjQJRVbNC0VFQWlXRY+11mTkxXFiIq+rvGKMpv/kGVFqjUYnkFKo5Wz/MRF5SX9EWLRv/3IWM2dG7pEKD7oAQAA`

And I want to decompress it using gzip.
I spent almost 2 hours on this now and can't seem to find out how to do this.
Does anyone know? I am new to Kotlin and I've never done that before.

Comment: it is base64 encoded string, you need to decode it first and then unzip

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`java.util.Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) to convert the Base-64 to binary. Then ungzip that.